# Server architecture for simple real-time online game

Tags: server, network-programming, real-time

I'm making a simple online game as a school project.
It's basically a classic snake game where the last player standing wins.

When a client presses an arrow key the server is notified and the snake direction is changed.

I'm thinking about how the clients should be informed about the current direction of each snake -  which one do you think is a better choice?

**Choice A:** The server stores the current direction of snakes in some data structure. Clients request the directions on each tick.

**Choice B:** Each client hosts it's own server in addition to the main server. When a client does a keypress, the main server receives it and broadcasts it to each client server.

I'm thinking that Choice A would be simple in the sense that there's no need for additional servers but... Choice B would bypass the need to request the game state at a regular interval.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by designing game logic then work on the implementation of the game logic.

I think I would start something like this

consider there are 2 players then I will make the play area a grid and have snakes positions in a kind of multi dimensional matrix and pass them around between players

coming to server architecture I would suggest doing it as one daemon thread running server and other threads as client and each client processes its own logic

which would look something like this http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html

Happy coding !!!

Comment: Thx for the answer. The game is already programmed as an offline-version. The only data i need to pass around are the changes in direction of each snake, the positions can be interpolated from there.